# Navbar no se despliega con bootstrap 4.5.3 (cdn) responsive?

Tags: html, bootstrap, navbar

Hola estoy practicando el navbar y me pasa que instalo la versión (via cdn) 4.5.3 de bootstrap y al momento de achicar la página, el menú no se despliega. Pero si pongo la versión 4.0.0 ahí sí funciona correctamente el responsive. Pero no entiendo qué hago mal para que la versión 4.5.3 no funcione.

---

Agregué al <-head-> éste script que tenía de casualidad y funciona pero tendría que funcionar con el 4..5.3 solo:     script; src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous">script>

Muchas Gracias por su tiempo.

Éste es el código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bootstrap Website</title>
    <!-- BOOTSTRAP 4 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- GOOGLE FONTS -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Titillium+Web:wght@200;300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


    <!-- SCROLL REVEAL -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal"></script>
    <!-- CUSTOM CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">


</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    <!-- BOOTSTRAP 4 SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola, a mi me funciona bien, prueba con otro navegador y si te funciona con el otro, borra el caché del navegador principal que usas.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta usar los enlaces proporcionados en el sitio web oficial de bootstrap o bootstrapcdn.
A veces se puede tener problemas con la carga de esos archivos, puedes descargar bootstrap e instalarlo en tu pc , si lo haces recuerda instalar tambien la libreria jquery y popper